# Como imprimir en console de C# un valor extraido de sql server

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Tengo este código, solo quiero mostrar un valor que obtengo desde una consulta a mi `DB` en la consola de `C#`

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Data.SqlClient;

    namespace PRUEBA
    {
        class Program
        {
            public object MessageBox { get; private set; }

            static void Main(string[] args)
            {

            }

            public void ConnectToSql()
            {

                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=name;Integrated Security=true;");
                con.Open();
                SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("SELECT ---", con);

                Console.WriteLine(com);

            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: donde lo llamo o como 
?\

Comment: aaah gracias, voy a probar

Comment: me da error el tostring...

Answer (score 2):

Tu hasta el momento lo único que haces es setear la consulta que deseas. Te falta ejecutarla y recorrer los posibles resultados que tenga esta consulta. Usamos un `SqlDataReader` para obtener la ejecución de tu consulta, luego hacemos un ciclo `while` donde recorramos las consultas hasta que no hayan mas registros y buscamos la columna que esperamos por FILA de registro.

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=name;Integrated Security=true;");
con.Open();
SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("SELECT ---", con);
using(SqlDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader()) 
{
    while (reader.Read()) 
    {
        //Debes saber bien que tipo de dato trae para convertirlo en caso que necesitaras por ejemplo :
        /*   
        int numero = Convert.ToInt32(reader["Columna"].ToString());
        */
        Console.WriteLine(reader["Columna"].ToString());
        Console.ReadLine();

    }

    con.Close();
}
```

Comment: cuando le doy start al programa, me abre a consola y la cierra de una vez..., cual puede ser el fallo??

Comment: Puedes especificar la consulta que haces? Porque si se abre consola y se cierra puede que no hayan registros por eso no imprime

Comment: Para que no te cierre la consola agrega esta línea de código al final:  Console.ReadLine();

Comment: Ese codigo espera la entrada por teclado o no? @Alejandro-2988924

Comment: Es correcto y disculpa, asumí que tu consola se cierra por que después de imprimir termina el programa, si pones el ReadLine te va a esperar a que presiones un Enter para seguir con la ejecución del programa y terminarlo. Esta recomendación es solo para ayudarte a debugear para liberación seguramente no lo necesitarás.

Comment: u sabes bastante de C#?? es que estoy empesando un proyecto desde cero y tengo muy poco tiempo pra entregarlo y la verdad mi conocimiento es limitado..

Comment: Comentame que necesitas mas o menos

Comment: Pasame tu correo para hablarlo major.

Comment: Veamos primero si se resolvio tu problema o no!

Comment: aun no, se habre y cierra la consola

Comment: Como te dije puedes actualizar la consulta y verificar si hay informacion en tu bd!

Comment: en la DB si hay informacion con esa consulta.

Comment: Entonces agrega a mi respuesta el codigo que @Alejandro-2988924  nos dijo! , modifique mi respuesta

Comment: no entiendo como hacerlo.

Comment: Copia mi respuesta y reemplaza la palabra "Columna" por el nombre de la columna que quieres visualizar!